# Why Treat 0 as True in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, programming-languages

I'm reading through the excellent [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) and have encountered the following code.

```
if 0
  true
else
  false
end
```

The above returns `true` and illustrates how unlike many languages (C being the obvious example), Ruby treats `0` as `true`. Rather than dismiss the behavior as idiosyncratic, I assume there is a good reason for this significant departure from convention. Python, for instance, treats `0` as `False`, just as one would expect.

In short, what is the rationale in designing Ruby to treat `0` as `true`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I'm guessing that Matz wanted conceptual simplicity of "truthiness" as such - the only "false" values are `false` and `nil`.  Period.

Using just `false` would be the cleanest but there is understandable need for including `nil`.  To include the integer zero as a special case might open the mental floodgates of questioning truthiness of other types.  What about strings, is `""` false?  And arrays, is `[]` false?  And hashes, is `{}` false?  Ad insanitum (see JavaScript)...

Comment: What's interesting, especially since I'm coming to ruby from python, is that all the examples you name (`[]`, `{}`, and `""`) are `false` in python. In my view, this only enhances the quirkiness of ruby.

Comment: And I'm sure people learning Python after knowing Ruby, Perl, JavaScript, Lua (etc.) find it quirky that those values aren't true!

Comment: Rails introduced #blank?, #present?, #empty?, and maybe more because, i think, 0, [], {}, and "" are not false. That make code bigger against ruby's less code principle.

Comment: in ReactJS (Javascript), I wrote `baseAmount && <MyComponent>` and suddenly my component disappeared when baseAmount was 0 as 0 is falsey in Javascript.

Comment: all your examples can be easily categorized as falsy without any danger, since they're pretty much the only ones; where it *might* get a little hairy is if you wanted to categorize stuff like `[""]` or `{[]}` as falsy but I'm not aware of any languages that do that

Answer (score 14):

In ruby, if exists, it's true. If not, it's false.

so, with Ruby null(no address assigned) and false are only false.

All others are true because it has address assigned to it.

I think of this way; "Does it exist?"

Comment: what you said is not true: `nil` is an object, so is `false`, and both of them exist :), they are instances of NilClass and FalseClass. the only false values are `false` and `nil`.

Comment: ...i.e., *"except for"* `false`

Comment: ok, yes everything is object in ruby. nil is the one and only instance of the NilClass class.I don't think it really matters because it's pointing to a instance that has null pointer. I regard this as 'not exist'.

Answer (score 7):

In Common Lisp, 0 is also treated as true. For example, the following code returns `true`.

```lisp
(if 0 'true 'false)
```

No doubt, Ruby is following the same design decision made in Lisp. In Lisp, only an empty list (represented by `nil`) is false.