# !0 is false in rails. Why?

Tags: ruby

I just got through a troubling bug in my rails application and I discovered that the problem was that !0 was false. I was assuming that, that should be true.

I was under the impression that ! operator would reverse the bits in an integer so 0 would become all 1's and hence would be true.

That is not the case, why?

Also note from the rails console:

```
1.9.3p286 :002 > !0
 => false 
1.9.3p286 :003 > 0
 => 0 
1.9.3p286 :004 > !1
 => false 
1.9.3p286 :005 > !!0
 => true 
1.9.3p286 :006 > !0
 => false 
1.9.3p286 :007 > !23
 => false
```

Comment: From wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29): "Boolean evaluation of non-boolean data is strict: 0, "" and [] are all evaluated to true."

Comment: From the official docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#UF

Comment: Bit operation is irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Treat 0 as True in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387515/why-treat-0-as-true-in-ruby)

Answer (score 13):

Because `0` is not equivalent to `false`. `0` is an integer value and the boolean value of all integers is `true`. The only things that evaluate to `false` are `nil` and, explicitly, `false`.

Given that `0` is `true`, `!0` is, intuitively, `false`.

`!` is not a bit-wise operator, it is a logical `NOT`. Perhaps you meant `~0`?

Comment: Thanks Ant P. I didn't know the boolean value of 0 is true in ruby. I guess in C boolean value of 0 is false.

Comment: This answer is strongly misleading. Whether or not `0` is equivalent to `false` is irrelevant. `nil` is not equivalent to `false`, but is falesy. There is also no such thing as "boolean value of (all) integers", and is also misleading to write as if `0` is `true`; it is not `true`, but is truthy. And `nil` does not evaluate to `false`; it is falesy. Overall, your answer is highly inaccurate and misleading.

Comment: I used the terms "truthy" and "falsy" as shorthand for "satisfying a condition" and "not satisfying a condition". I don't think that is unclear, nor will it be confusing with any Ruby object. What is problematic with your answer is that you referred to actual Ruby objects `true` and `false` (with backquotes), and wrote as if things other than that are equivalent to them. That is clearly wrong. `0 == true` is `false`, not `true`. You wrote as if is.

Answer (score 6):

In ruby there are only two values that evaluate to false in logical expressions: false and nil.
Since 0 is neither of them, it evaluates to true and thus !true equals false.

Answer (score 4):

From [this blog](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/true-false-and-nil-objects-in-ruby/)

> Most objects in Ruby will have a boolean value of true. Only two
>   objects have a boolean value of false, these are the false object
>   itself and the nil object.

So any integer (even 0) has a boolean value `true`. And thus `!0` evaluates to `false`