# What's the boolean value of `0` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

After looking at the behavior of these expressions:

```
1 and 0 #=> 0 
0 and 1 #=> 1

1 and true #=> true
0 and true #=> true
```

to me, it is more like ruby returns the right side value of a logic gate regardless of the evaluated result of the logical expression. I am looking for the reason for it.

Comment: 0 is true in ruby. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387515/why-treat-0-as-true-in-ruby

Comment: A quick test for the logical value: !!0

Comment: Could you add the results you were expecting?

Comment: @Stefan I was expecting >> 0 and 1 => 0 ; infact this is what "or" gate would result.

Comment: @LochanaEgodawele it can be confusing that 0 is a true-value. You have to use `true` and `false` along with `and` to get the desired behavior, i.e. `false and true #=> false`. (or any other combination of true-value and false-value)

Answer (score 6):

Two things you need to know:

1. `and` (and `&&`) returns the first operand if it's false, otherwise returns the second operand.
2. Anything other than `false` and `nil` is true, including `0`.

Comment: Thanks. 0 returns true is strange though. I thought it should be 1 instead.

Comment: @LochanaEgodawele its just different than C, because in language with more built-in data types (like Ruby) treating `0` as `false` leads to problems - should `"0"` (a String) also be zero? Should `"0.0"`? If so, should `""` be? And `[]`? If you take a look at crazy PHP truth tables, you will understand that simple convention that only `false` and `nil` are falsey is actually pretty good thing.

Comment: One could argue that it's strange to have a concept of *truthy* and *falsey*. It would be easier to understand if `false` was false and `true` was true without the exception of `nil` and "everything but `nil` and `false`". But Ruby wants to be nice, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Ruby is behaving properly, but might be confusing if you're coming from another language. This confusion is most often caused by:

1. Not understanding truth-values and false-values in Ruby, especially when evaluating the truthiness of [control expressions](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html).
2. Using a flow-control operator like `and` to test for equality instead of `==`.
3. Misunderstanding how the parser sees your "comparison" as two separate expressions.

To fix the problem you describe, use an equality operator to test for truthiness. A more detailed explanation follows.

### Ruby Returns the Last Expression Evaluated

In Ruby, every expression returns a value. When you evaluate expressions like:

```
1 and 0 #=> 0
```

you aren't checking the truthiness of each expression as you would be with an actual Boolean-returning expression such as:

```
!!(1 and 0) #=> true
```

Instead, you are simply evaluating two expressions in sequence, unless the first expression evaluates as *nil* or *false* and short-circuits the evaluation. Either way, Ruby returns the value of the last expression evaluated. In this case, you could get the same result with:

```
1; 0 #=> 0
```

### What the Parser Sees

Using Ruby standard libraries, you can see what the parser sees. For example:

```
require 'pp'
require 'ripper'

pp Ripper.sexp '1 and 0'
#=> [:program, [[:binary, [:@int, "1", [1, 0]], :and, [:@int, "0", [1, 6]]]]]
```

The S-expression may be a little clearer and easier to read when using the [ruby_parser gem](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby_parser) instead of [Ripper](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html). For example:

```
require 'pp'
require 'ruby_parser'

pp RubyParser.new.parse '1 and 0'
#=> s(:and, s(:lit, 1), s(:lit, 0))
```

Either way, since the first expression `1` evaluates as an Integer literal (e.g. something other than *nil* or *false*), `0` is then evaluated. The second Integer literal also evaluates as true, and therefore the entire expression is true (which is irrelevant in this context) and returns 0, since `0` was the last expression evaluated.

### What You Actually Want

In Ruby, [all values other than *nil* or *false* are *true*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Booleans+and+nil). Instead of the [and](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/keywords_rdoc.html) operator, you usually want to compare expressions with an equality operator such as [==](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F) or forcibly-cast an expression into a Boolean context with `!!`. For example:

```
# Evaluate equality and return a Boolean result.
1 == 1 #=> true
0 == 1 #=> false

# Evaluate whether an expression is equal to true. In this case,
# the double-negation of `!!` casts each Integer as a Boolean value.
!!1 == true #=> true
!!0 == true #=> true

# Use `and` flow-control operator to evaluate right-hand expression
# if the left-hand side evaluates as truthy.
(1) and (true)  #=> true
(1) and (false) #=> false
```