# !! (double bang) meaning in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What does `!!` mean in the following method?

```
def include?(record)
  !!@association.include?(record)
end
```

Comment: It's called double bang (!!).

Comment: `!!` converts "truthy" values (everything other than `nil` and `false`) to `true` and "falsy" values (`nil` or `false`) to `false`. `!!x` means `!(!x)`. If `x` is truthy, `!x` is `false`; if `x` is falsey, `!x` is true. The first `!` then flips `false` to `true` and `true` to `false`.  For example, `!!7 => !(!7) => !false => true` and `!!nil => !(!nil) => !true => false`.

Comment: You have deleted a recent question, give a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m9gmjc2w/) ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It casts a variable into type boolean and determine its truthy or falsy value

For example:-

```
# Numbers...
!!1 # => true
!!0 # => true

# Numbers as strings...
!!'1' # => true
!!'0' # => false

# Truthy strings (case insensitive)...
!!'true'  # => true  (alias: 't')
!!'false' # => false (alias: 'f')
!!'yes'   # => false (alias: 'y')
!!'no'    # => false (alias: 'n')

# Booleans...
!!true  # => true
!!false # => false

# Nil...
!!nil # => false
```

Comment: !!0 is true. [Only `nil` and `false` are falsy in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433335/whats-the-boolean-value-of-0-in-ruby)

Comment: For the `# Truthy strings (case insensitive)` section my understanding is that those all return as `true`. Tested them out in out in http://rubyfiddle.com/ with running `print(!!'false')` and followed suit with all examples and their aliases. All returned true. I am working on growing my Ruby knowledge so please feel free to lmk if I a missing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It helps you get boolean results.

For Example:

```
a = nil
!a
#=> true
!!a
#=> false
```

Similarly

```
a = 1
!a
#=> false
!!a
#=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

The double exclamation mark will convert the result to a boolean value so that, in this case, if `@assication.include?(record)` returns `nil` that will get converted to `false`.